# Different definitions of 'countable set'

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

There are a number of different definitions of 'countable set', all equivalent given a strong enough (classical) system.  The obvious ones (injection to $\mathbb{N}$, bijection to $\mathbb{N}$, enumerable as a sequence) have a fairly clear provenance (and use cases).

I am interested in the following definition.  For simplicity, all sets are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Call a set $X$ *weakly countable* if there is a sequence of finite sets $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $X=\cup_n X_n$.

Let us say that a set $Z$ is *finite* if for any large enough finite sequence $\sigma$ of real numbers, there is always a real in $\sigma$ not in $Z$.

My question is whether the notion of weakly countable has been studied previously?  If so, be so kind to provide references.

Comment: The notion of a real number is so advanced that I feel that "countable" should be introduced BEFORE "real number".

==== Also, there are two meanings to "countable" -- "infinite countable" and "the utmost countable". Which one do you want to stress? (or both?).

Comment: With respect, what's the question? Is it whether this notion has been used before, and if so, references?

Comment: @WlodAA: by "the utmost countable" do you mean "at most countable"?

Comment: @WlodAA: Why? Nothing in the definition of the reals requires the notion of countability.

Comment: I feel like the question is a bit ill-specified. What's your definition of "finite set" and "sequence of finite sets"? Do we have countable choice? Depending on the answers, weak countability may or may not coincide with countability. Also, what David Roberts said: what is the question?

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: I am currently studying (classically) the properties of weak countability in reverse math.   I am interested if people have looked at this previously, e.g. in textbooks.

Comment: The perhaps you could tag the qustion with `reference-request`.

Comment: Surely your weakly countable implies a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ (in ZF).  Enumerate elements by the first $X_n$ they enter, and within a given $X_n$ by the order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Dan Turetsky: correct.  Of course, Kleene's $\exists^3$ is all you need for this, but nothing weaker qua (conventional) comprehension.  In particular, even if one has access to $S_k^2$ for all $k^0$ (which can decide $\Pi_k^1$-formulas), you cannot obtain a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To me, the novel and subtle definition here is not your “weakly countable”, but what you’re calling “finite”.  Is that definition previously studied somewhere?  And might it be worth giving it a different name than just “finite”, to point out that it’s where the subtlety lies?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: thanks for that interesting remark.  That notion (of finiteness) came up when studying functions of bounded variation and regulated functions in weak systems.  It somehow seems to be the only notion that works well in that context.